# Output format for dates in a range, with bash

Tags: bash, date

I am trying to use bash to produce a list of dates and times between a starting point and an end point.

I would like the output to be in mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm format.

On the command line, the command:

```
date +"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"
```

Produces the output that I am looking for.

When I use the line that is presently commented out, I get an error.

```
date: extra operand ‘%H:%M’
Try 'date --help' for more information.
```

I am not sure how to alter the script to produce the output that I am looking for.

```
DATE=date
#FORMAT="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"
FORMAT="%m/%d/%Y"
start=`$DATE +$FORMAT -d "2013-05-06"`
end=`$DATE +$FORMAT -d "2013-09-16"`
now=$start
while [[ "$now" < "$end" ]] ; do
  now=`$DATE +$FORMAT -d "$now + 1 day"`
  echo "$now"
done
```

I have played around with adding an 00:00 after the start and end times, but that did not work.

Any ideas where I am getting the output format wrong?

Code from:
https://ocroquette.wordpress.com/2013/04/21/how-to-generate-a-list-of-dates-from-the-shell-bash/

Comment: Generally, it is better to use `start=$(date +"$FORMAT" …)` rather than using back-quotes ``start=`date +"$FORMAT" …` ``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `FORMAT="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"` you need quotes because it contains a space, so:

```
now=`$DATE +"$FORMAT" -d "$now + 1 day"`
```

Also, I do not think that you can compare dates like that. You might need timestamp:

```
date +%s
```

Comment: Or go with an ISO 8601 variant notation: `%Y/%m/%d %H:%M` which can be sorted alphanumerically into date order.  ISO 8601 puts the year before the month before the day before the time, and one of its many benefits is that the result can be sorted into date order with a simple alphanumeric sort.

Comment: I like using the yyyy/mm/dd format, but the application I am trying to import into wants it in the format stated. Having things sort with a simple ls is nice though.

Comment: When I replace the now line, with the one with quotes, I still get the same error concerning an extra operand.

Comment: I am using:

    DATE=date
    FORMAT="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"
    #FORMAT="%m/%d/%Y"
    start=`$DATE +$FORMAT -d "2013-05-06"`
    end=`$DATE +$FORMAT -d "2013-09-16"`
    now=$start
    while [[ "$now" < "$end" ]] ; do
      now=`$DATE +"$FORMAT" -d "$now + 1 day"`
      #now=`$DATE +$FORMAT -d "$now + 1 day"`
      echo "$now"
    done

Comment: @CS3000911 Any format that contains space(s) has to have the quotes around